# How do I create a live USB installer from a Mac?

Tags: installation, live-usb, mac

I have a new PC and I want to install Ubuntu on it. I only have a Mac to create the installation medium. How can I create a live USB for installation?

Answer (score 0):

Unetbootin is a great application available for Linux, Windows and Mac OS. This can be downloaded from [Unetbootin Homepage](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).

Unetbootin has a fairly simple interface to use. You can choose from a list of Linux Distributions to download from the web or select a local image.